# Convert timespan into hhh:mm:ss to insert into mySQL time type fields

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, timespan

This seems like a newbie question but I am really struggling with it.

I have a time field in mysql database.  I am using vb.net 2012.  I am trying to insert amounts of time into the time field.  I've settled on using a text box and having the user enter the amount of time as a decimal (1:30:00 = 1.5).  My problem is that these timespans can be over 24 hours long and vb wants to convert it into a format that contains days.

ex.  100.5 hours gets converted to 4.04:30:00

I would like it to show as 100:30:00 so that I can insert it into my database.

I'm open to alternate suggestions.

Please help me.  I've wasted more than enough time on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(100, 30, 1)
    Dim foo As String = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", _
                                     Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)
```